# Grunt: flow control

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-prompt

From my own task, I what to use `grunt-prompt` to ask a boolean Q and then run or don't run a task based on the answer.

The problem is that grunt.task.run() does not actually run a task but rather adds it into a queue.

so if I do from my own task:

```
grunt.task.run('prompt:ask');
if (grunt.config('answer')) { 
   grunt.task.run('do:something');
}
```

When the if executes the prompt task did not actually run yet...

Is there a recommended way to do this?

maybe some syntax like:

```
grunt.task.run('prompt:ask').andThen(function(){
   if (grunt.config('answer')) { 
      grunt.task.run('do:something');
   }
})
```

Note To Self: Check what grunt returns from grunt.task.run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the [`then` option](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-prompt#then) for the plugin to execute code once an answer is entered:

```
prompt: {
  ask: {
    options: {
      questions: [
        // your question here...
      ],
      then: function(results) {
        if (results[0].whatever) {  // obviously you'll need to update this...
          grunt.task.run('prompt:ask');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this is an option but a very un natural one...
[in the sense that the logic I want to apply is not a part of the prompting task but rather at a higher level...]
I might end up setting up the `then` function from the controlling function. 
I was hoping that grunt would have some form of a better flow control mechanism.

Comment: This is the only way that I know to interact with the results of a user prompt with this plugin.

Comment: what if the Q was not about this specific plugin? but any output from a first task? that needs to be considered before deciding wather to run or not run some second task?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how you would do that cleanly.